# stop nusoap inserting empty nodes in php

Tags: php, soap, nusoap

Is it possible to change the behaviour of nusoap to stop it creating empty nodes when i dont include them in my array? I am using a wsdl that defines the request, but while the field is not required, minOccurances is set to 1.  If I removed the node completely and test it in soap, it works without any problems. Submitting the node however, causes issues...

```
$request = array('field1' => 'value1',
                 'field2' => 'value2');

$this->_client->call('AddressLookup', $request, '', '', $this->_getHeader());
```

gives me the following in the body of my request...

```
<field1>value1</field1>
<field2>value2</field2>
<field3/>
```

I dont wan't field3 to be included in my request at all. Is this possible?